# Heat Transfer Problem , 1 Dimensional Conduction Extended Surfaces

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-transfer, thermal-conduction

[image]enter image description here

[image]

[image]

So I am having issue solving this problem, I solved one part by the fact that in the given distance of 2L , 2 tubes are involved so I can find the heat conducted per unit length.
Whereas I don't understand how to use fourier's law to compute the temperature at the insulation point even though I know the maximum temperature is going to be at the insulation point. Please give me any suggestions.

EDIT:
[image]

[image]

I have seen your answer and edited, Its not possible for the heat to flow in 
x direction under steady state conditions because all of the absorber plate is
receiving the same amount of radiation flux from the sun hence why would
heat flow in x.
Temperature should be maximum along the lower surface of the absorber plate 
at the insulation points, I've made an analogy to fluid flow, its like you have made 2 holes in the bottom of a tank of water and water is flowing out.
I've attached 2 more pages to show my intuition.

Comment: See https://www.sku.ac.ir/Datafiles/BookLibrary/45/John%20A.%20Duffie,%20William%20A.%20Beckman(auth.)-Solar%20Engineering%20of%20Thermal%20Processes,%20Fourth%20Edition%20(2013).pdf

Comment: I have had a overview of the book but the issue is I couldn't find information that I could apply to my problem.

Comment: They cover flat plate collectors, tubes and tube spacing.

Comment: Oh I see, I've had a overview of a chapter, yes it does talk about those things but its at master's level so I don't know how exactly to apply (and I  can't seem to understand it well enough) , like my problem doesn't even include the things the book is talking about (like loss coefficient, temperature distribution etc). I am only studying 1D steady state conduction (at bachelor's level) and I was just introduced to these concepts. I'm really sorry if I'm causing inconvenience .

Comment: Then check out other books on heat transfer, such as one by Simonson... see https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-349-15605-4 but often available in secondhand bookshops - where I found mine.

Comment: So you are saying that I should search for the solution to this problem in books? Like through theory?

Comment: Why not? that's how I solved my heat transfer problems and got to grips with cfd...Working for a solution is more rewarding than being given it on a plate...

Comment: That is true but the time constraint makes it tough because it takes a lot of time and right now time is short. But working on every solution must take a lot of time and if there are multiple subjects you have to study then its not possible to spend time like that on each and every one. Besides I thought on this platform as long as I have done my homework I can get directions as to where I could have gone wrong.

Comment: So I went over the first 2 chapters and the chapter on Extended Surfaces of  Heat Transfer by Simonson, yet I still could not find anything that I could use to solve my problem, I think case-specific thought processes cannot be achieved by reading/understanding theory/ or in this case I wasn't able to find it. :/

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is simply in making the statement $dT/dx = 0$. The statement $dT/dx$ is for an insulating wall, and neither the radiation surface nor the tube locations are insulating. The top surface has the maximum temperature **AND** it has an incoming heat flux. The surface at the tubes has the minimum temperature and has an exiting heat flux. As a final hint, the steady state profile across the plate will be linear $dT/dx$.

Comment: I am trying to get what you are trying to say but I cannot visualize it, I have made edits to the post to support what my thought process is. Also you are saying that top surface has maximum temperature, I don't understand how/why is that possible as well.